# Android GPS works at first but later returns null values

Tags: java, android, sqlite, gps

This is a simple GPS logger. The latitude and longitude values get logged into an SQLite database every 10 seconds.

This works when my app is run for the first time, but when the app is run again the location values are null and my table never gets updated with the values.

```java
public class GPSService extends Service {

    public static final String TAG = GPSService.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID = 1000;
    public static final String GPS_WAKE_LOCK = "GPSWakeLock";
    public static final int GPS_TIME_THRESHOLD = 10000; // 10 sec
    public static final int GPS_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD = 10; // 10 meters
    public static EventBus bus = EventBus.getDefault();
    private LocationManager lm;
    private LocationManager locationManager2;
    private LocationListener locationListener;
    private Location location = null;
    private Timer timer;
    private DumpTask dumpTask = null;
    private DatabaseHelper myDb = null;
    private static boolean active = false;
    private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = null;
    public static Double Latitude;
    public static Double Longitude;
    public static int TotalNoOfStations;
    public float[] result = new float[2];
    public int k;
    public static Boolean SwitchOffAlarmService=false;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        bus.register(this);
        timer = new Timer();
        myDb = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(this);
        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager2 = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate ");
        k=0;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "destroyed");
        bus.unregister(this);
        timer.cancel();
        stopService(new Intent(this,GPSService.class));
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void onEvent(GPSLoggerCommand e) {
        if (e.command == GPSLoggerCommand.START && !active) {
            Log.d(TAG, "start gps logger");
            getRouteDetails();
            MainActivity.LocationServiceStarted=true;
            getLatLonFromDB();

            try {
                lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, GPS_TIME_THRESHOLD, GPS_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD, locationListener);
            }catch (SecurityException ex){
                Log.e(TAG, "onEvent " + ex.toString());
            }

            dumpTask = new DumpTask();
            timer.schedule(dumpTask, GPS_TIME_THRESHOLD, GPS_TIME_THRESHOLD);
            active = true;
        } else if (e.command == GPSLoggerCommand.STOP && active) {
            Log.d(TAG, "stop gps logger");
            dumpTask.cancel();
            try {
                lm.removeUpdates(locationListener);
            }catch(SecurityException ex){
                Log.e(TAG, "onEvent " + ex);
            }
            bus.post(new StatusReply("total rows " + myDb.getRowsCount()));
            stopForeground(true);
            active = false;
            locationManager2.sendExtraCommand(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,"delete_aiding_data",null);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            locationManager2.sendExtraCommand("gps","force_xtra_injection",bundle);
            locationManager2.sendExtraCommand("gps","fource_time_injection",bundle);
            stopService(new Intent(this,GPSService.class));
        } else if (e.command == GPSLoggerCommand.STATUS) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onEvent send message " + active);
            bus.post(new GPSLoggerStatus(active));
        }
    }

    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            if (loc != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged " + loc.getLatitude() + ":" + loc.getLongitude());
                location = loc;
            }
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onProviderDisabled");
            Toast.makeText(GPSService.this, "Service Canceled due to GPS being Disabled!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            GPSLoggerCommand c;
            c = new GPSLoggerCommand(GPSLoggerCommand.STOP);
            bus.post(c);
            MainActivity.GPServiceStarted=false;
            MainActivity.LocationServiceStarted=false;
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onProviderEnabled");
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            String showStatus = null;
            if (status == LocationProvider.AVAILABLE)
                showStatus = "Available";
            if (status == LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE)
                showStatus = "Temporarily Unavailable";
            if (status == LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE)
                showStatus = "Out of Service";
            Log.d(TAG, "onStatusChanged " + showStatus);
        }

    }

    public class DumpTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d(TAG, "dump to base");
            if (location != null) {
                // write to database
            }
        }
    }


    public static void StopServiceFunction()
    {
        GPSLoggerCommand c;
        c = new GPSLoggerCommand(GPSLoggerCommand.STOP);
        bus.post(c);
        MainActivity.GPServiceStarted=false;
        MainActivity.LocationServiceStarted=false;
        active = false;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
implement GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener
```

in your activity and past below code in override methods

```
 @Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

    if (location == null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);

    } else {

        mCurrentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        mCurrentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText(this,  mCurrentLongitude + " * ********"+mCurrentLatitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```